# Is there an efficient quantum circuit that create a random permuntation matrix?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, complexity-theory, quantum-circuit

Suppose we want to generate a random, random according to some probability distribution, unitary permutation matrix that is applied to an input of $n$ qubits. So is there an efficient polynomial time and polynomial space circuit that can generate a random unitary permutation matrix (which is of course dimension a positive power of $2$ or $2^n$)? If there is no polynomial algorithm (in the above question) then what is the most efficient algorithm instead?

Comment: The number of such random permutation matrices is $f(n) =(2^n)!$. The logarithm of $f(n)$ grows (more than) exponentially with $n$. So you cannot even write down such a random permutation matrix (in any encoding) in space growing polynomially with $n$.

Comment: @MartinSeysen But can you transform your comment into a  rigorous  proof for an answer to my question?

Comment: My argument is purely information theroretic: There is no language in which you can encode each matrix of the given set in space polynomial in $n$. I assume that the output of the desired algorithm is a circuit for a specific  (uniform distributed) unitary permutation matrix matrix selected at random. Then there is no polynimial-time algorithm that outputs such a circuit, since the average output would be too long.  But I'm not sure whether this is what you are looking for.